# How to compare two list<object> in C# and retain only the items that don't have duplicates?

Tags: c#

Here are two lists:

```
var list1 = new List<UserGroupMap> 
        { 
            new UserGroupMap { UserId = "1", GroupId = "1", FormGroupFlag = "1", GroupDescription = "desc1", GroupName = "g1"}, 
            new UserGroupMap { UserId = "1", GroupId = "2", FormGroupFlag = "1", GroupDescription = "desc1", GroupName = "g1"},
            new UserGroupMap { UserId = "1", GroupId = "3", FormGroupFlag = "1", GroupDescription = "desc1", GroupName = "g1"},
            new UserGroupMap { UserId = "2", GroupId = "3", FormGroupFlag = "1", GroupDescription = "desc1", GroupName = "g1"} 
        };

        var list2 = new List<UserGroupMap> 
        { 
            new UserGroupMap { UserId = "1", GroupId = "1", FormGroupFlag = "1", GroupDescription = "desc1", GroupName = "g1"}, 
            new UserGroupMap { UserId = "1", GroupId = "2", FormGroupFlag = "1", GroupDescription = "desc1", GroupName = "g1"},
            new UserGroupMap { UserId = "1", GroupId = "3", FormGroupFlag = "1", GroupDescription = "desc1", GroupName = "g1"},
            new UserGroupMap { UserId = "2", GroupId = "3", FormGroupFlag = "1", GroupDescription = "desc1", GroupName = "g1"},
            new UserGroupMap { UserId = "4", GroupId = "3", FormGroupFlag = "1", GroupDescription = "desc1", GroupName = "g1"}, 
            new UserGroupMap { UserId = "3", GroupId = "3", FormGroupFlag = "1", GroupDescription = "desc1", GroupName = "g1"}, 
        };
```

now what I want to happen is to get a list that doesn't have duplicates, basically compare list1 and list2 return only the items that are duplicate.

based from the sample what it should return are the last two items from list 2 since they are not in list1.

Comment: The answers below are right, but it's important to think about what you mean *exactly* by duplicate. For example take `var a = new UserGroupMap {UserId = "1", GroupId = "1", FormGroupFlag = "1"}; var b = new UserGroupMap {UserId = "1", GroupId = "1", FormGroupFlag = "1"};` does new List(a, b) contain duplicates? What about after the call b.GroupId = "2"?

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
list2.Except(list1).Concat(list1.Except(list2));
```

Comment: This doesn't work until UserGroupMap does not override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. It's also not clear how this "returns  the last two items from list 2 which are not in list1."

Comment: Assuming you handle equality somewhere, why the `.Distinct()`? And why the `.Union(...)` instead of `.Concat(...)`? The OP didn't mention to remove the duplicates from 'self'.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, the task can be solved with Linq by using

```
var Result = list1.Concat(list2).Except(list1.Intersect(list2));
```

however this probably requires `UserGroupMap` to implement the interface `IEquatable<UserGroupMap>` in a suitable way, unless `UserGroupMap` is a `struct`. If implementation of `IEquatable<UserGroupMap>` for some reason is impossible, the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of `Except` which takes a custom comparison as an argument can be used, as well as the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of `Intersect` which takes a custom comparison as an argument.

Comment: How does this take care of the `retain only the items that don't have duplicates`?

Comment: @Maarten Thanks for the comment; I corrected the answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I was mistaken, but updated the answer.

Comment: I actually want to do this without using linq and I'm currently struggling do you have any idea how to do it? Oh btw thank you for the 1st solution you provided it actually works though I actually need something that doesn't use linq. Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering why you would not use Linq. Anyway, can `IEquatable<UserGroupMap>` be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

> what it should return are the last two items from list 2 since they
>   are not in list1.

**Update** If you can't use LINQ you could use a [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299875(v=vs.110).aspx) to search and remove duplicates. You have to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`(or implement `IEquatable<T>` what i did):

```
public class UserGroupMap :  IEquatable<UserGroupMap>
{ 
    public string UserId {get;set;}
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public string FormGroupFlag { get; set; }
    public string GroupDescription { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;

            hash = hash * 23 + (UserId ?? "").GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + (GroupId ?? "").GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + (FormGroupFlag ?? "").GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + (GroupDescription ?? "").GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + (GroupName ?? "").GetHashCode();

            return hash;
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(UserGroupMap other)
    {
        if(other == null) return false;
        if(Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        return this.UserId == other.UserId
            && this.GroupId == other.GroupId
            && this.FormGroupFlag == other.FormGroupFlag
            && this.GroupDescription == other.GroupDescription
            && this.GroupName == other.GroupName;
    }    
}
```

Now it's easy:

```
var uniqueInList2 = new HashSet<UserGroupMap>(list2);
uniqueInList2.ExceptWith(list1);
```

Result: your two desired objects from `list2`.

Note that this approach also removes duplicates from `list2`, i'm not sure if that's desired.

---

Old answer:

```
var onlyInTwo = list2
  .Where(x => !list1.Any(x2 => x.UserId == x2.UserId && x.FormGroupFlag == x2.FormGroupFlag && x.GroupDescription == x2.GroupDescription && x.GroupName == x2.GroupName));
```

You could also implement a custom [`IEqalityComparer<UserGroupMap>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms132151%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which can be used for example in [`Enumerable.Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx). Then it's simple and efficient:

```
var onlyInTwo = list2.Except(list1, new UserGroupMapComparer());
```

Another way is let `UserGroupMap`  override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` or to implement the [`IEquatable<UserGroupMap>` interface.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I actually want to do this without using linq and I'm currently struggling do you have any idea how to do it? Oh btw thank you for the 1st solution you provided it actually works though I actually need something that doesn't use linq. Thanks!

Comment: @TimSchmelter I was just updating my answer with `GetHashCode()` implemetation and then see your is same with mine. So, don't think that it is copy :)

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev: really. But you have an issue with null values in `Equals` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Computer doesn't know how to compare your custom class instances. You have some choices and one of them is to create your own comparer which must implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface:

```
sealed class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<UserGroupMap>
{
    public bool Equals(UserGroupMap x, UserGroupMap y)
    {
        if (x == null)
            return y == null;
        else if (y == null)
            return false;
        else
            return x.UserId.Equals(y.UserId) 
                 && x.GroupId.Equals(y.GroupId)
                 && x.FormGroupFlag.Equals(y.FormGroupFlag)
                 && x.GroupDescription.Equals(y.GroupDescription)
                 && x.GroupName.Equals(y.GroupName);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(UserGroupMap obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;

            hash = hash * 23 + (obj.UserId ?? "").GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + (obj.GroupId ?? "").GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + (obj.FormGroupFlag ?? "").GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + (obj.GroupDescription ?? "").GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + (obj.GroupName ?? "").GetHashCode();

            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

And then use [`Except()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from the `System.Linq` namespace to find the difference of two sequences by using the default equality comparer:

```
var result = list2.Except(list1, new MyComparer()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question if you want:

1: results from list2 that aren't in list1, as in the small sample set example:

> what it should return are the last two items from list 2 since they are not in list1

or 2: if you want to find the non-duplicates from both lists

> to get a list that doesn't have duplicates

or 3: if you want to find the duplicates from both lists

> basically compare list1 and list2 return only the items that are duplicate.

3: is trivial, so probably not that:

```
list1.Concat(list2).Duplicate(new UserGroupMap());
```

Assuming you've added `IEqualityComparer` to your UserGroupMap (or added as a separate comparer).

1: has been answered

2: has not been answered, so here you go:

```
var result = (from item in list1.Concat(list2)
              group item by new { item.UserId, item.GroupId, item.FormGroupFlag, item.GroupDescription, item.GroupName }
              into groups
              where groups.Count() == 1
              select groups)
            .SelectMany(x => x);
```

this will then work even if you swap the content of list1 and list2.