# Compare 2 listviews and put the non-matching items in third listview in Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have two list views in windows form, in which I have data. There are some records which are common while others are not. I need to get those non-matching  records. What should I do to get only non-matching records.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297972/how-to-compare-two-listobject-in-c-sharp-and-retain-only-the-items-that-dont/30298052#30298052

Comment: This has been answered in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18099298/5015269

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing two Lists and returning the distinct values and the differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099054/comparing-two-lists-and-returning-the-distinct-values-and-the-differences)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Linq Except method to get a list of none matching items.

Comment: Using Sergei's code to initialise the two views then something like this would give you the difference which would need adding to the third ListView

      var lv1Contents = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(xx => xx.Content);
      var lv1Contents = listView2.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(xx => xx.Content);
      var diff = lv1Contents.Except(lv2Contents);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 using Sustem.Linq; // Add this line. 
                    //If it doesn't work add a reference to System.Core.dll

    namespace FormAppp
    {
        public class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
            }

            ....

            void DoInitialization()
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem("1"));
                listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem("2"));
                listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem("3"));


                listView2.Items.Add(new ListViewItem("1"));
                listView2.Items.Add(new ListViewItem("3"));

                var list1Source = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>();
                var list2Source = listView2.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>();

                var list3Source = list1Source.Where(x => 
                 list2Source.All(y => y.Text != x.Text));
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: just add this: using System.Linq;

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Take a look at the comments. I hope it will help you.

Comment: As for your question about Where(x=>list2Source.All(.....). I can't answer it in brief. I can offer you to read these article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx.